# What is a medium-sized dataset for scikit learn clustering algorithms?

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

On scikit learn's clusting algorithm [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) they give a comparison chart for different clustering algorithms describing their scalability and usecases. What is considered a medium sized n_samples? I have a dataset which has 40 different features and a million rows, is this a medium-sized or large dataset?

Does this change if I try and engineer additional polynomial features e.g. taking all quadric monomials from the 40 features?

Comment: Why do you need a "definition" of medium vs. large? Clearly this is subjective. It's large when it takes too long to compute. So how long does it take?

Comment: Also, quadratic terms etc. tend to just make things worse (unless you have *supervised* says of learning feature relevance). Clustering is extremely sensitive to scaling. And you probably don't even know how to scale your 40 existing features to get *valid and meaningful* results. Don't fall for the trap that things would get easier if you just add more data. You need better and cleaner data, not more data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Well, do you have any suggestions for reading material? How can I decide how to scale my features?

Comment: Sorry, no. Engineering features is an art, not science. So I don't know any good guide on that.